# Execute Macro after data refresh

Tags: excel, vba

The macro below updates Column A with a hyperlink function.

How do I run this after a data refresh on my query/datasource is clicked?

I tried writing a change condition on my worksheet.

```
Sub InsertHyperlinkFormulaInCell()

currentRow = 2   
While Cells(currentRow, 2) <> "" 'check whether Column B is empty, stop if it is
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Query").Cells(currentRow, 1) = "=HYPERLINK(CONCAT(X" & currentRow & ",B" & 
currentRow & "),W" & currentRow & ")"
currentRow = currentRow + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: normally the better practice is to [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) and write the formula to the entire range in one step, instead of looping.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.afterrefresh

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually refreshing your query, do it from the macro and then continue with your code.

```
Sub InsertHyperlinkFormulaInCell()

Query.QueryTable.Refresh

'rest of your code here

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, I also added a line to deactivate the background refresh option. Much appreciated!
                     
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("query1").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("query1").Refresh